# How to serialize the JSON response?

Tags: deserialize

i'm trying to convert the json response as sObject(Case).
   but i'm little confusion to map external sys fields with sobject fields

this is my JSON response :

```
{"result":[{"short_description":"Can't read email","sys_id":"9c573169c611228700193229fff72400","incident_state":"7","urgency":"1","impact":"1","active":"false"}]}
```

this is what i have done :

```
res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());     
String jsonText =res.getBody();
Map<String, Object> cObjMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonText);
String cObjJson = JSON.serialize(cObjMap.get('Data'));
// Why again :
(Map<String, Object> cObjMapFurious = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(cObjJson);
String cObjJsonDrunk = JSON.serialize(cObjMapFurious);
try
   {
     SObject customObject = (SObject)JSON.deserialize(cObjJsonDrunk, Sobject.class);
     System.debug(' Accomplished: '+customObject);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.debug(' @@@@@ Don\'t visible '+ex.getMessage());
                }
```

This is my wrapper class, how should I map with case?

```
global class Deserialization{

     public String short_description;
     public String sys_id;
     public String incident_state;
     public String urgency;
     public String impact;
     public String active;

     global Deserialization(String short_description1,String sys_id1,String incident_state1,String urgency1,String impact1,String active1){

          short_description = short_description1;
          sys_id = sys_id1;
          incident_state = incident_state1;
          urgency =  urgency1;
          impact =  impact1;
          active = active1;
     }

}
```

Comment: You should create a wrapper class same as the response returned by the http request and from the wrapper data you can create `Case` no need to do repeated things you are doing here.

Comment: this is my wrapper class how should i map with case?

Comment: uh ill take a stab at it, one second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete you answer, but you need to build the object that you are expecting.. I use [Json to Apex](https://www.adminbooster.com/tool/json2apex), I take that as a starting point, I don't build it exactly how it tells me, I have quirks I like to do.  But this will work for you.  I'll leave it in this format so you can execute anon it..

```
String deserlize = '{"result":[{"short_description":"Cant read email","sys_id":"9c573169c611228700193229fff72400","incident_state":"7","urgency":"1","impact":"1","active":"false"}]}';

ResponseResult theresult = (ResponseResult)JSON.deserialize(deserlize,  ResponseResult.class);

System.debug('result' + theresult);

public class ResponseResult
{
    public ResponseResult()
    {
        result = new List<ResponseData>();
    }

    public List<ResponseData> result;

}

public class ResponseData 
{
    public String short_description {get;set;}  //Can't read email
    public String sys_id  {get;set;}    //9c573169c611228700193229fff72400
    public String incident_state  {get;set;}    //7
    public String urgency  {get;set;}   //1
    public String impact  {get;set;}    //1
    public String active  {get;set;}    //false
}
```

This will return an object looking like this.. You will then need to loop through this object and build whatever else you need out of it

```
ResponseResult:[result=(ResponseData:[active=false, impact=1, incident_state=7, short_description=Cant read email, sys_id=9c573169c611228700193229fff72400, urgency=1])]
```